# Crash with multiline UIAlertView message

Tags: iphone, cocoa-touch, uialertview

Crash log

```
-[UIAlertView displayScrollerIndicators]: unrecognized selector sent to instance 0x1fbaf120
```

The code is:

```
UIAlertView *alert = [[UIAlertView alloc] initWithTitle:NSLocalizedString(@"Some info",nil) message:str delegate:self cancelButtonTitle:NSLocalizedString(@"Close", nil) otherButtonTitles: nil];
alert.tag = 12345;
[alert show];
```

Where `str` is huge Multiline Text with `\n` Characters.

Comment: Somewhere you were placing alertview object inplace of scrollView object

Comment: search for occurrence of `displayScrollerIndicators` in your class check if u are not calling it with `alert's` object.

Comment: Please provide the value of `str`, so that the issue can be reproduced.

Comment: @rptwsthi UIAlertView calls displayScrollerIndicators when number of text lines equal or more then 13. It is not showing scrollable textview anymore, it just crashes!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Funny ... this seems to be a bug in the `UIAlertView` class.

I just did a quick test, showing an `UIAlertView` with a message consisting of several lines - and on the iPad simulator (iOS 6.1) the alert view **breaks when displaying 13 lines or more**. It seems that after 12 lines the alert view does not get larger anymore, and apparently then some error happens because it thinks it has to scroll, but there is not scroll view available.

So, make sure you don't show more than 12 lines in an UIAlertView I would say ...

**UPDATE:**

I just made another test - and I found the crash is not (only) connected to the amount of lines, but to the setting of the `tag` property of the alert view - when you don't set the `tag`, it still works and shows a scrollview - just when you set a tag it crashes with more than 12 lines ... strange.

**UPDATE 2 (and last):**

It seems that if the integer value for `tag` is smaller than 12345 (I tested 1,12,123,1234) it also works - just a higher `tag` value leads to the crash. Still strange, as the `tag` property is an `NSInteger` and as such should have at least 32 bit, so 12345 should not be any problem overflow-wise ...

Comment: In previous versions of iOS when message was 13 or more lines an scrollable textview appears in UIAlertView, now it just crashes... Looks like there are alert view bug

Comment: WOW, unbelievable :) Thanx for your help

Comment: Thanks.. the Tag 12345 caused me this crash in iOS6 (Bug).. And with iOS7 it works without any change..

Answer (score 0):

Somewhere in your code you are calling `displayScrollerIndicators` using a `UIAlertView object`

Answer (score 0):

I think you are doing something wrong.You are calling other class method with `UIAlertView`'s object. And you can't call this method because this method is not under of `UIAlertView` class.

Answer (score 0):

The error message “`unrecognized selector sent to instance XXX`” means that the app is trying to call a method that doesn’t exist. Often this happens because the method’s being called on the wrong object.